# Chebyshev inequality problem

Tags: means, variance

I'm trying to solve following problem:

*The symmetric coin is tossed 1600 times. What is the probability that the head will be shown up more than 1200 times?*

As I know, I should use Chebyshev inequality, but I could not find mean and variance.
Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider random variable $X$ which is a number of times that head was show up. So, if we denote as $\xi_i$ the showing of head in $i$-th experiment, we will have

$$X = \sum_{i=1}^{1600}\xi_i.$$

The expectation is linear over them, so
$$E(X) = E\left(\sum_{i=1}^{1600}\xi_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{1600}E(\xi_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{1600}\frac12 = 800.$$

All of the experiments are independent from each other, so the variance will be linear as well

$$\text{Var}(X) = \text{Var}\left(\sum_{i=1}^{1600}\xi_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{1600}\text{Var}(\xi_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{1600}\frac12\left(1-\frac12\right) = 400.$$

So, now you are able to apply Chebyshev inequality. Do you need further help with Chebyshev inequality?

Comment: I understood, mean is a total number of attemts divided by two (in other words we just found average).... But I am confused with understanding of variance (what is it)..why in variance 1/2 * (1-1/2) ?

Comment: @Pavel, this is a standard result for the binomial distribution. If we have an experiment, which terminates with either success $(+1)$ (with prob. $p$) or fail $(-1)$ (with prob. $1-p$), then the variance of getting $+1$ will be $p(1-p)$. You can take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Variance

Comment: am I right , that we take 1/2  because to get head or tail in this case, probability is 1/2?

Comment: @Pavel, you're right